# Loop a horizontal scrolling div with fixed positions

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div `.project-container` which contains a bunch of divs with set heights and widths. I've set this up to slide to a position, that increases, on click using some jQuery.

```
$("#right").click(function() {
    $(".project-container").animate(
            {"left": "+=1060px"},
            "slow");
});
$("#left").click(function() {
    $(".project-container").animate(
            {"left": "-=1060px"},
            "slow");
});
```

Each div within the `.project-container` is positioned absoluted of each other using the following jQuery

```
$('.one-project').each(function(i){
  $(this).css({ left: 1060 * i });
});
```

I click on the right button and it slides to the next div, and as I click it continues to move.

My issue is that at the end of the div set, I'm trying to work out if it can jump back to the beginning div (position) again. Also, is there any possibility of this always going back to the second div, and always starting on the second div?

Here is what I have so far: http://goo.gl/Cbr8R

Any help would be good. Trying a custom build and getting stuck. I'm sure it's easy to you guys ;)

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEVER mess with gallery directions. if you click RIGHT everyone expects a gallery to slide to the left revealing the "RIGHT" content.

here's the basic for ANY gallery logic:

- create a counter `C`
- on click increase / decrease that counter
- animate to `minus left` just doing `- C * OneSlideWidth`
- fix the counter **if** `-1` (LEFT -1 behav.) to the number of `numberOfSlides-1`
- for any other click do `counter % numberOfSlides`

And here's the logic:

```
var W = $('.slide').width(); // one slide width
var N = $('.slide').length;  // number of slides
var C = 0;                   // counter

$('#slider').width( W*N );   // (if needed) to make space for left floated images

$('#left, #right').click(function(){
     var myID = this.id == 'right' ? C++ : C-- ;
     C= C===-1 ? N-1 : C%N ;
     $('#slider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 1000 );
});
```

### *[jsBin demo with gallery essentials](http://jsbin.com/itimoq/1/edit)*

Code Explanation:

1. `var myID = this.id=='right' ? C++ : C-- ;`
   A dummy var just to do our `C` de/incrementations using Ternary operator (?:)

   > [statement] ? [if true] : [if false]
2. `C= C===-1 ? N-1 : C%N ;`
   Again using Ternary Op.:
   If `C==0` (initial state) and after a **LEFT** click: `C=== -1` than reset it to the last slide (`N-1`)
   For all other **LEFT** and **RIGHT** clicks the `C % N` will be applied:
   `%` is the Modulo operator and it will return a reminder of the division of `C` and `N`.
   For `C` is almost always less than `N` it will return the current `C` **UNLESS** 
   at the last slide, if we click **RIGHT** than `C===N` and `%` will transform it to `0`.

    that applyed to our animation logic `left: -C*W` is actually `left: -0` (first slide).

Comment: Hi @roXon - thanks again for the help. And yes about the gallery directions... was just a test for now but nice heads up :) I tried using your logic. I didn't keep the code '$(this).css({ left: 1060 * i });' for each slide. They seem to jumble on top. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Richard Fixed some errors in my example and creating a sample demo

Comment: @Richard added the demo in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going to try it in the morning with my setup as I have absolute positioned divs that take up full widths etc so it might get complicated. But thanks again for the help and the explanation - this helps a lot. I wouldn't have ever come up with this.

Comment: Many many thanks. This is almost perfect. I understand the code a lot more so I should be able to continue. If you have a look: http://goo.gl/7DZVn :) The width per slide is correct, although I need it to slide 1060 rather than 960 (width per slide) due to the offset. I'll work out how to add on values. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks again @roXon. I worked out how to increase the slide length :) Thanks. One thing. Is there any way to set it to start at the second slide but with the ability to slide to the first? But it always resets and starts at the second?

Comment: Thank you! All pretty much makes sense. I guess if I tinker with `C= C===-1 ? N-1 : C%N ;` I should be able to always make it return to the second slide and never the first unless they click 'left' on the second slide.

Comment: @Richard Sorry I wrote it wrongly. Now I realized what you want. DON'T TOUCH THE COUNTER LOGIC! UNDO. Clone the last image, increase slider width by "one extra width" and animate using the old animation logic but always by an extra "slide width" to get the desired image! http://jsbin.com/itimoq/9/edit Simple as that it cannot be! :)

Comment: @Richard don't even try to play with the counter logic to do what you want, or after a few hours you'll realize it was not worth the time. Simply fix the animation positions by an 'extra' width. Like I said

Comment: @Richard and again after days you still use the wrong 'left' 'right' animation interface experience

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20271/discussion-between-richard-and-roxon)

Comment: Seriously, folks. Nicest and most helpful guy here ^^